# code first generated database cannot be seen in sql server but it acts as if it has been created

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, ef-code-first, dbset

I have a WCF which makes call to my EF. I have made the WCF my start up project and one of the services in there a start up file.

When i run this project and pass in the right parameter as what i have in my Seed method, i get an object back from **Login** method.

This means the database should have been created on my local server in SQL Server right ?. When i change the code first classes, i get an error that the stating that the model has changed so this is because the database already exists right ?.

I can see the database in Visual studio Server explorer but it is disconnected and when i try to click on it it's asking for username and password when i have not configured it to have one in my **Web.Config**

What could be my issue. I want to see my EF database in SQL server.

**User Context**

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserContext()
        : base("Local")
    {
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserTask> Tasks { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Tasks = new List<UserTask>();
    }
}
```

**User Service (WCF)**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public User Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new Exception("User name or password cannot be empty");
        }

        User user = null;
        using (var userContext = new UserContext())
        {
            user =
                userContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(
                    u => u.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) &&
                         u.Password.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- local dev -->
    <add name="Local" connectionString="server=.;database=TodoTest;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run VS as Administrator.
Also, public ICollection Tasks { get; set; } should be virtual.

About your question "i get an error that the stating that the model has changed so this is because the database already exists?" the answer is yes... :)